# Final Answer for volume of a spherical tank not valid

Tags: c++, c

I created this program that is supposed to basically use the formula V=Pi*h^2(3r-h)/3 but my final answer isn't adding up.

For example: if I substitute 1 for the radius and 2 for height, I should get 4.18 but instead through the program I am getting -1.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double calculatevolume(double);

double main() {
    double radius, height;
    double sum;    //for storing the radius of the reservoir given by the user
    //for storing the calculated volume of the water.

    printf("Please enter the Radius in meters first and then the Height in meters right after:\n"); //Displays the message on the screen

    scanf("%lf",&radius);
    printf("Value of r: %f\n", radius);

    scanf("%lf",&height);
    printf("Value of h: %f\n", height);

    sum = calculatevolume(sum);

    printf("For a reservoir of radius: %.2f m\nAnd a water depth: %.2f m\nThe water volume is: %.2f m^3\n",radius,height,sum);

    system("PAUSE");
}

double calculatevolume(double sum) {
    double radius;
    double height;

    sum = ((((3 * radius) - height)/3) * 3.14 * height * height);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: "isn't adding up" is not a meaningful problem description.

Comment: What's not adding up and what does your main return a double?

Comment: check you function. radius and height and empty -- add them to parametre

Comment: How can a sphere have a radius and a height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, you should pass height and radius to the function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double calculatevolume(double,double,double);
double main() {
    double radius, height;
    double sum;    //for storing the radius of the reservoir given by the user
     //for storing the calculated volume of the water.

    printf("Please enter the Radius in meters first and then the Height in meters right after:\n"); //Displays the message on the screen

    scanf("%lf", &radius);
    printf("Value of r: %f\n", radius);


    scanf("%lf", &height);
    printf("Value of h: %f\n", , height);

    sum = calculatevolume(sum,radius,height);

    printf("For a reservoir of radius: %.2f m\nAnd a water depth: %.2f m\nThe water volume is: %.2f m^3\n",radius,height,sum);

    system("PAUSE");
}

double calculatevolume(double sum, double radius, double height) {
    sum = ((((3 * radius) - height)/3) * 3.14 * height * height);
    return sum;
}
```

You may also delete sum from the function header, it's not necessary to pass it

Comment: check the function **calculatevolume** it now get 3 parametre instead of 1 in your code

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't realize you're supposed to include all the variables in the parameter. I am new to programming but thank you so much

Comment: welcome, yes you have to include them or you can make them global variable, i suggest to read about **scopes of variable** and you will learn more

Comment: here is a usefull link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

Comment: Done and Thank you so much once again!